# SQL - Multi Where clauses

Tags: sql-server

This huge `where` clause is generating output for all the countries however I have mentioned Mexico. Do I need to change the order of the clauses.

Please note there is one [exec] in the beginning and other 10 at the end under OR condition. Could this be the issue.

```
Select *
from tblKPI
WHERE Date>='2016-01-01' AND Date<='2019-01-01' 
AND [Exec] LIKE 'joselinemasis' 
AND Customer LIKE '%%' 
AND Country LIKE 'Mexico' 
AND Payroll LIKE '%%' OR [exec] = 'Albenalukanova' 
OR [exec] = 'amitkumar' OR [exec] = 'AsthaChadha' 
OR [exec] = 'barbaranyari' OR [exec] = 'BereniceParedes' 
OR [exec] = 'Bhawnasingh' OR [exec] = 'edgaralcantara' 
OR [exec] = 'elidethcisneros' OR [exec] = 'FruzsinaKaraszi' 
OR [exec] = 'joselinemasis'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It is quite unclear from the code in your question.

Comment: Why do you even need `AND Customer LIKE '%%' ` and `AND Payroll LIKE '%%'` in you `WHERE` clause? That filters nothing. You can try usin a `IN` clause and listing all values for `[exec]` in that, rather than having so many `OR` clauses

Comment: Actually, I am developing a tool which has a SQL server as a database. and the manager wants to filter the report for these where clause where. Customer Country. For exec he wants to have records for multiple users.

Comment: Let me try and use IN if that works. Thanks for the advise

Comment: Your first `exec` with `like` has `AND`

    `AND [Exec] LIKE 'joselinemasis'` 

So how can be `LIKE 'joselinemasis'`  and also equal to anything else?

Put everythin inside one `IN` and make sure use parenthesis to separate your `OR` and `AND`